# Dynamic TextView on ActionBar

Tags: android, menu, bluetooth, android-actionbar

I need to implement a TextView in the ActionBar. This TextView shows the status of the bluetooth connection so it will update depending of this status.

I'm not talking about changing ActionBar's title, but adding a textview f.e. under the title or at the right side.

At the moment, what I have done is create an item in the menu.xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/statusTextview"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Disconected" />
```

Then Add it on the mainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bluetooth, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.statusTextview);
    tvStatus = (TextView) menuItem.getActionView();
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

But It isn't working correctly. At first time should show `Disconnected` status and doesn't show nothing. Then when the status changes and the textview must update, it throws a **NPE**.

Comment: Here is an answer that uses an XML layout instead: [TextView on Action Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24716629/383414)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can Add TextView manually in

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
```

By following code.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(getString(R.string.matchmacking)+"  ");
            tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.WHITE));
            tv.setOnClickListener(this);
            tv.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            tv.setTextSize(14);
            menu.add(0, FILTER_ID, 1, R.string.matchmacking).setActionView(tv).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

and if you want to access text view then make tv as class variable.

Comment: If I do this, I still have to mantain the definiton of the item in the menu.xml? Cause this way I'm creating the item programmatically, and i don't know what refereces the FILTER_ID def

Comment: Thank you. Very precise and exact solution

Comment: what is the 'FILTER_ID'?

Comment: `FILTER_ID` doesn't seem to be a pre-defined constant. Checking the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). You can pass `0` as the second argument to `add()`, if you do not need a unique ID for the item.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone still needs this:

You can dynamically set the text property of menu item by calling the `setTitle("Your new string or String resource id")` method on the menu item. That way, you do not have to cast the ActionView into a TextView. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    String bluetoothStatus = "Connected"; //get from source

   menu.findItem(R.id.the_id_of_the_menu_item).setTitle(bluetoothStatus);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```