# TextView on Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, textview

I am trying to add a textView on the actionBar which I can dynamically edit.
Why is the below code not working????

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="@style/TextMedium"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

In the onCreate method of activity,

```
View addView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.spinner_select_text, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(addView,new ActionBar.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        TextView label =  (TextView)addView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        label.setText("Hello");
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working".

Comment: plz first check related question , [like](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22554097/3419997)

Comment: Why don't you simply change the ActionBar title?

Answer (score 4):

You also need `actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);`

FYI you can give the action bar your layout id instead of inflating it yourself:

```
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.spinner_select_text);

    TextView label = (TextView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```